# How can I convert a BMP to JPEG without saving to file?

Tags: c#, file, encoding, type-conversion, jpeg

I have a BMP image object which contains a BMP image, how can I convert it to JPEG format without saving to file?

All I need to know is the size of the JPEG file after the conversion, so If I have several BMP images, I want to convert each one of them into a JPEG and then see the size of each one.

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Save it to a MemoryStream.

Answer (score 2):

Just save it stream. and look size.

```
private ImageCodecInfo GetEncoder(ImageFormat format)
    {

        ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();

        foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs)
        {
            if (codec.FormatID == format.Guid)
            {
                return codec;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\ercan.acar\Pictures\Current CR Sticker.PNG");
        ImageCodecInfo jpgEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder myEncoder =System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality;

        EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);

        EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder,
            50L);
        myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
        Stream stream=new MemoryStream();
        bmp1.Save(stream, jpgEncoder,myEncoderParameters);
        //bmp1.Save(@"C:\Users\ercan.acar\Documents\TestPhotoQualityFifty.jpg",);

        var size = stream.Length;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a nuget package like Magick.NET or similar.
Why reinventing the wheel and care about encoding, conversion adjustments, optimization if other have done this already for you.