# How save png as jpg without saving the file in dir

Tags: image, powershell, export-to-excel, bmp, fromfile

I'm using FromFile to get the image out of files, and it has the following error for the png's on the FromFile line:

> Exception calling "FromFile" with "1" argument(s): "The given path's
> format is not supported."

So, I'm trying to convert the bmp's to jpg, (see convert line above FromFile below) but all the examples I see (that seem usable) are [saving the file](https://www.techanarchy.net/bmp-to-jpg-the-powershell-way/).  I don't want to save the file in the dir. All I need is the image format, so FromFile can use it like [this example](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel/issues/1041). I saw [ConvertTo-Jpeg](https://github.com/DavidAnson/ConvertTo-Jpeg), but I don't think this is a standard powershell module, or don't see how to install it.

I saw [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55162000/how-can-i-convert-a-bmp-to-jpeg-without-saving-to-file), but I don't think that would leave the image in the format needed by FromFile.

This is my code:

```
               $imageFile2 = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $ImageFullBasePath -Include @("*.bmp","*.jpg","*.png") | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "$($pictureName)"}  #$imageFile | Select-String -Pattern '$($pictureName)' -AllMatches
                

                Write-Host $imageFile2
                if($imageFile2.Exists)
                {
                    if($imageFile2 -Match "png")
                    {
                        $imageFile2 | .\ConvertTo-Jpeg #I don't think this will work with FromFile below
                    }
                    $image = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile($imageFile2)  step
                }
                else {
                    Write-Host "$($imageFile2) does not exist"
                }
```

And then I put it in excel:

```
  $xlsx = $result | Export-Excel -Path $outFilePath -WorksheetName $errCode -Autosize -AutoFilter -FreezeTopRow -BoldTopRow  -PassThru # -ClearSheet can't ClearSheet every time or it clears previous data  ###left off
  $ws = $xlsx.Workbook.Worksheets[$errCode]
  $ws.Dimension.Columns  #number of columns
  $tempRowCount = $ws.Dimension.Rows     #number of rows

  #only change width of 3rd column
  $ws.Column(3).Width
  $ws.Column(3).Width = 100

  #Change all row heights
  for ($row = 2 ;( $row -le $tempRowCount ); $row++)
  {
     #Write-Host $($ws.Dimension.Rows)
     #Write-Host $($row)
     $ws.Row($row).Height
     $ws.Row($row).Height = 150
     #place the image in spreadsheet
     #https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel/issues/1041  https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel/issues/993
     $drawingName = "$($row.PictureID)_Col3_$($row)" #Name_ColumnIndex_RowIndex   
     Write-Host $image
     $picture = $ws.Drawings.AddPicture("$drawingName",$image)
     $picture.SetPosition($row - 1, 0, 3 - 1, 0)
     if($ws.Row($row).Height -lt $image.Height * (375/500)) {
         $ws.Row($row).Height = $image.Height * (375/500)
     }
     if($ws.Column(3).Width -lt $image.Width * (17/120)){
        $ws.Column(3).Width = $image.Width * (17/120)
     }
  }
```

Update:

I just wanted to reiterate that FromFile can't be used for a png image. So where [Hey Scripting Guy](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/hey-scripting-guy-weekend-scripter-converting-png-files-to-jpeg-format/) saves the image like this doesn't work:

```
$image = [drawing.image]::FromFile($imageFile2)
```

Comment: The error you're receiving is not about the _image format_, it's about the _path_ you've passed to `FromFile()`. Try `$image = [drawing.image]::FromFile($imageFile2.FullName)` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the $imageFile2 path has 2 filenames in it.  It must be that two met the Get-ChildItem/Where-Object/match criteria. The images look identical, but have similar names, so will be easy to process.  After I split the names, it does FromFile ok.